# Single Sign on for RDS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication, rds

I currently have an RDS farm which is used for running remote apps for a large group of users.

When logging in these users must authenticate to the RDS web page to view their list of applications. Then they authenticate again upon clicking the application the require.

How can I enable this to use the users current windows authentication so they do not have to log in at each step. Ideally since the user is logged in to their local machine with their windows account, they should not need to continuously authenticate.

Comment: Do you have Integrated Windows Authentication enabled for your sites?

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to address your need, although I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/08/11/introducing-web-single-sign-on-for-remoteapp-and-desktop-connections.aspx